# How to manager a complicated page in iOS code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, architecture, delegates

Like Microsoft App on iPad. A single page contains multiple stuffs. Normally we may write everything in a UIViewController, which will also contains lots of views, delegates, notifications, and interactions.

For example, we might operate views which were created by other delegates.

So, how could we manage all these functions?

Comment: You can have more than one view controller on screen, you should read about container view controllers : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html. The rest is tricky and depends on having a good architecture as to not allow your classes to grow too big.

Answer (score 0):

### Divide the view into separate UIViewControllers

You can nest `UIViewControllers` if you have more complex views. It helps you to divide code between different classes.

In the main `UIViewController` just add the child view of the second `UIViewController` and call `addChildViewController:`.

### Use MVVM

MVC design pattern is pretty bad at separating concerns. The ViewController ends up pretty big, because it contains business logic and view logic. If you have a huge view, [you should think about using MVVM](http://yourcodesucksexception.blogspot.com/2015/01/why-i-use-mvvm-instead-of-mvc.html) instead. It helps you to separate concerns by having the view logic in the ViewController and business logic in the ViewModel. It also works pretty well with data binding because it helps you think of the view as an independent module that just reacts to changes in the ViewModel.